# Triggering downstream job manually

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

[image]Can anyone explain how to stop the triggering of a downstream job 
I have jobs

- -MainJOB

  ```
           1. job1
           2. job2
  ```

I trigger a MainJob and once Job1 is completed & i need to trigger the Job2 manually.
But Now, After job1 completes , job2 getting triggered automatically

Comment: Have you added `job2` in the downstream of `job1`?

Comment: no, job1 and job2 both are downstream jobs. MainJob is Upstream job

Comment: What is that Main job means...Is it a job which triggers others two or what do you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Post-build actions` section of `job1`, if `job2` is added there in `Build other projects` option then uncheck it and save `job1`.

Now, if you trigger `job1` it won't trigger `job2`.

Comment: I am triggering main job. so automatically job1 triggers . And now i need job 2 not to trigger, until i trigger it manually

Answer (score 0):

Check the **triggering option** in Jenkins **Build Configuration** in **Post Build** Options try to uncheck the Option. So no other job triggers.

Comment: I dont have Triggering option in post build. In MainJOB configuration, inside "Add Build step" option, i have two Multijob phase. One for job1 and other for job2

Comment: can you post the screen how the configuration is?